# /root/Desktop/SEG3502/BookStoreAppV1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, glassfish

Can anybody help me with this please?
Whenever I run my application, I get the following error :

```
Starting GlassFish Server
GlassFish Server is running.
In-place deployment at /root/Desktop/SEG3502/Lab3/build/web
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
/root/Desktop/SEG3502/Lab3/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 58 seconds)
```

Comment: What part exactly of the phrase *"See the server log for details."* didn't you understand? Please act accordingly and include those details in the question in case you don't understand that either.

Answer (score 0):

First undeploy any previous version of your app, stop glassfish server, clean and build the current version and start/deploy again.